# C# Moving selected mail items to external directory

Tags: c#, outlook, vsto, outlook-addin

Can anyone provide an example of how to move selected inbox items to an external directory on the computer for example C:/Mails

I am not able to get the function to run after I have selected the mails into a folder on button click

I have tried the following code but i am not able to call this function on button click

```
internal static IEnumerable<MailItem> GetSelectedEmails()
        {
            foreach (MailItem email in new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application().ActiveExplorer().Selection)
            {
                yield return email;
            }
        }
```

onClick Code

```
private void MyButton_click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{
    Globals.ThisAddIn.GetSelectedEmails(); 
}
```

Thanks

Comment: _" i am not able to call this function on button click"_ - why not?

Comment: @stuartd even if i call the function function from a button onClick event the control is not going in the for loop

Comment: @stuartd I am only unable to call this particular function, but i am able to call other functions

Comment: So the problem isn't in this code, it's in the code that calls this code?

Comment: I have updated the onClick code in the question, I am able to call other function with the same code but not his one

Comment: So what happens when you add a breakpoint at `Globals.ThisAddIn.GetSelectedEmails();` and then step in? What happens if you capture the return (i.e. `var selectedEmails = …`) and add an extra line of code in the function to make sure something is returned (i.e. `yield return new MailItem()` before the foreach loop)?

Comment: Can you enumerate if you drop "yield"?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko it shows ````"'ThisAddIn.GetSelectedEmails()': not all code paths return a value " ```` if i drop "yield"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement in that loop only execute when the next element of the returned collection is actually used (that's the point of yield). If the caller does not request an element, the code is not executed.

What does the calling code look like?

Change the code to the following - then the foreach loop will run:

```
internal static IEnumerable<MailItem> GetSelectedEmails()
        {
            var list = new List<MailItem>();
            foreach (MailItem email in new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook.Application().ActiveExplorer().Selection)
            {
                list.Add(email);
            }
            return list; 
        }
```

Comment: I want to call the loop on button click

Comment: The button click event handler does nothing with the returned collection.

Comment: Or get rid of "yield" (see the updated answer above).